# Immersive mode in iOS Cordova apps - how to?

Tags: cordova

I use the following plugin for my Cordova Android apps for immersive mode:
https://github.com/UlisesCeca/cordova-plugin-fullscreen

Basically like:

```
AndroidFullScreen.showUnderStatusBar(successFunction, errorFunction);
```

The question is, how do I enable immersive mode for **iOS**? I've searched everywhere and can't find a way..

Answer (score 1):

Just use `<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />` and use [cordova-plugin-statusbar](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/) along with `StatusBar.hide();`

You can also check the `hide status bar` checkbox in xcode